# Async load settings before static constructor

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, windows-runtime, mvvm-light

I was just finishing my new app, but I got stuck. My app is divided into 2 parts - remote and local. What I need is to register a class for interface based on some async deserialized application settings. Here is the 'idea code'

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        // It can't work :(((
        if(await SettingsManager.LoadSettings().EnableRemote) // <<<<<<
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMyService, MyRemoteService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMyService, MyLocalService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SomeOtherViewModel>();
    }
```

How could I solve it? The settings are serialized in an XML file in Isolated Storage of my WinRT app. Please, can you think of any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use async for loading configurations? Is there anyway of knowing when the settings have been loaded? If there is, then load them before hand and wait until it is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sort of breaks the IoC pattern to register bindings asynchronously.  You'll need to incorporate the async settings into a wrapper class.  This wrapper class should be responsible for:

1. loading the settings
2. providing the actual implementation of `IMyService`

If `IMyService` has synchronous methods, then you'll probably have to change it, either to provide async versions of all the methods, or to provide a `Ready` property + event, so that consumers will know when it is safe to access.  But if it's a service, its methods are probably already async, right?

As an illustration, let's call the wrapper class `MyServiceWrapper`.  It will load the settings when it is first constructed, and pass through all asynchronous methods in `IMyService` (for example, `SomeMethodAsync` as below).

```
public interface IMyService
{
    Task SomeMethodAsync(Action<bool> callback);
}

public class MyServiceWrapper : IMyService
{
    private IMyService _impl = null;
    private IMyService _remote, _local;
    private bool _loaded = false;
    private object _sync = new object();

    public Task SomeMethodAsync(Action<bool> callback)
    {
        // first make sure the settings have been loaded
        await LoadSettings();
        _impl.SomeMethodAsync(callback);
    }

    public MyServiceWrapper(MyRemoteService remoteService, MyLocalService localService)
    {
        _remote = remoteService;
        _local = localService;
        LoadSettings();
    }

    private async Task<bool> LoadSettings()
    {
        if (_loaded)
            return true;
        // lock to prevent multiple threads from loading the settings
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_loaded)
                return true;

            if(await SettingsManager.LoadSettings().EnableRemote)
                _impl = _remote;
            else
                _impl = _local;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now you can have your DI container register:

- `MyRemoteService` -> `MyRemoteService`
- `MyLocalService` -> `MyLocalService`
- `IMyService` -> `MyServiceWrapper`

Comment: You may want to add `try/catch` inside `LoadSettings` and propagate any error via `SettingsLoaded` event too. Otherwise, if anything throws inside `LoadSettings`, there's no way to handle it outside `LoadSettings`.

Comment: NP, but it's still a bit confusing, what's the `EnableRemote` on `LoadSettings().EnableRemote` ? Did you mean `if(await SettingsManager.LoadSettings())` ?

Comment: @Noseratio I have no idea -- I took that directly from the OP.  All we know is that it is some kind of app/user setting that is to be loaded asynchronously, somehow / for some reason.

Comment: Sorry if I bug you, I just don't wanna put a hijacked version of your answer. May I suggest to just store a task inside `MyServiceWrapper` constructor: `this._initTask = LoadSettings()`, then simply await it inside `SomeMethodAsync`: `await this._initTask`. That'd solve both the error handling and thread-safety concerns.

Comment: @Noseratio np, but I'm a bit out of my depth with this async stuff.  Are you saying that `_initTask` would never run twice simultaneously? (ie, if say `SomeMethod1` called `await _initTask`, then `SomeMethod2` called it again before the first was complete)?

Comment: @Noseratio in any case, please don't worry about "hijacking" -- if you can post a better answer, feel free to borrow/modify mine.  I don't think either of us will be getting much rep from this, either way. :)

Comment: Yep, `await _initTask` would continue instantly for any subsequent `awaits`: once a task is done, it's done. +1 for the idea, but you're right, let's leave it up to the OP to clarify it further, if he's ever interested :)